# Wordpress pagination <a> links click and change to "active" but don't redirect

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, pagination

I've searched through many similar pagination issues and have not found a solution to this exact problem.

Pagination seems to be working perfectly, links are generated properly and pages are physically generated appropriately, though the nav links do not click through properly.

I've checked the generated html for the links (Which display correctly like this: [image: navigation buttons])

```
<!--PAGINATION START-->
<div class="ast_pagenav">
    <div class="pagi_border" style="width: 220px;">
        <a class="page-numbers current" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2?paged=1" target="_blank">1</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=2/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">2</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=3/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=4/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">4</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=5/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2" style="margin-right: 0px;">5</a>
        <dt></dt>
    </div>
</div>
```

URL: http://bscserver.com/bsg/blog/

Though when clicked, a nav element will successfully change to the "current" state / class, though the href redirect does not action.
[image: nav icon when clicked]

```
<!--PAGINATION START-->
<div class="ast_pagenav">
    <div class="pagi_border" style="width: 220px;">
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2?paged=1" target="_blank">1</a>
        <a class="page-numbers current" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=2/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">2</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=3/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=4/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2">4</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=5/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2" style="margin-right: 0px;">5</a>
        <dt></dt>
    </div>
</div>
```

URL: STILL http://bscserver.com/bsg/blog/ even though the clicked element has href="http://bscserver.com/bsg?paged=2/

Any idea what may be causing my links not to click through? Thanks.

Javascript that seems to be associated:

```
jQuery('.ast_pagenav a').each(function(){

    <?php if(is_category() || is_search() || is_author()) {  ?>
    this.href = this.href.replace('/page/', '&paged=');
    <?php }else{ ?>
    this.href = this.href.replace('/page/', '?paged=');
    <?php } ?>
});
    jQuery('.ast_pagenav a').on('click', function(e)  {
    jQuery('.ast_pagenav a, span.page-numbers').removeClass('current'); // remove if already existant
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');


    e.preventDefault();


    <?php wp_reset_query();
    $template = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true );
```

The entire extract seems to be quite bulky though I think this is the relevant part.

Comment: you must be using some JavaScript you're not showing here, right?

Comment: I'm assuming there's something that came standard with the theme I'm using - I'll fish around for it and post it in an edit. Thank you for the reminder!

Comment: look for something like `$('.page-numbers')` or `jQuery('.page-numbers')`

Comment: Actually, I re-read your question and I don't think you have a problem. Everything works great except what shows in the URL bar, right?

Comment: The actual page doesn't change. It seems like the click is registering, though never redirects. & Thanks for the clue - will see if I can find it :)

Comment: What did you mean by "pages are physically generated properly?" I assumed you meant that the posts were showing. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: what is the name of the file you pulled that JS from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - when I click a nav element, nothing actually happens other than the element is selected as "active". It stays on the same page / selection of blog elements. When I say "pages are physically generated, I mean I can manually browse to /blog/page/2/ and /blog/page/3/ respectively, the content exists and is appropriate, though when I click on the nav icon for those pages, it doesn't (either) physically redirect me to the page OR pull the content from those pages (as with or without ajax pagination).

Comment: This `//Layout 5 Ajax END` is either misplaced or you have a missing `});` that should be above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: after comments

If the posts are not loading, your JS is preventing the default link behavior ( which is pretty normal ). What it should do in addition is call the page you want ( paged/2/ or paged/3/ whatever ) using Ajax and load the posts OR us JS to redirect to that page.

ORIGINAL ANSWER
I don't think you have an issue. Your JS is pulling those pages and loading them dynamically and there is really no need to change the address in the URL bar, in my opinion.

Comment: It looks like your load function is appending this `.lay5_wrap .single_post` to the URLs ( and probably getting a 404 error or worse ( like what you would get if you tried to browse to `http://bscserver.com/bsg/?page_id=49%3Fpaged%3D2?paged=1.lay5_wrap .single_post`

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. I removed the appended .lay5_wrap .single_post from my load function and viola - seems to be working.

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure it's working as intended, but I think you've taken it in the right direction.